# Could someone explain why the following gocode fails with goapp serve

Tags: google-app-engine, go

```
package helloworld

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"

  "appengine"
  "appengine/user"
)

func init() {
  fmt.Print("hello")
  http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  c := appengine.NewContext(r)
  u := user.Current(c)
  if u == nil {
    url, err := user.LoginURL(c, r.URL.String())
    if err != nil {
      http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
      return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Location", url)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
    return
  }
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %v!", u)
}
```

Throw the following error in `goapp serve` output

```
(saucy)adam@localhost:~/projects/ringed-land-605/default$ goapp serve -host 0.0.0.0 .
INFO     2014-06-08 23:57:47,862 devappserver2.py:716] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2014-06-08 23:57:47,877 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:48026
INFO     2014-06-08 23:57:47,923 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2014-06-08 23:57:47,925 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2014-06-08 23:57:48,759 http_runtime.py:262] bad runtime process port ['hello46591\n']
```

Removing the `fmt.Print()` fixes the issue. My question is why does that happen?

Comment: I know nothing about go. But look at fmt.Fprintf it expects w to be io.Writer , I don't think http.ResponseWriter is compliant with that interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When starting the runtime process, the [Go Development Server](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/devserver) (in the App Engine Go SDK) is reading the single line response found in your helloworld's `init`.

This modifies the `_start_process_flavor` flag in `http_runtime.py`; consequently, the HTTP runtime attempts to read the line for direction on which port to listen to.

> Read the single line response expected in the start process file. [...] The START_PROCESS_FILE flavor uses a file for the runtime instance to report back the port it is listening on.

In this case, `hello` isn't a valid port to listen on.

---

Try using Go's [`log`](http://golang.org/pkg/log/) package instead:

```
log.Print("hello")
```